# How to fix bad font rendering of Montserrat in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

We're using wkhtmltopdf to generate PDFs and need to use the font Montserrat, which is available from Google Fonts as a ttf.

The font seems to mostly work, but has rendering issues.  It looks like wkhtmltopdf has converted the font to a vector and applied some over-zealous smoothing.  Look in particular at the 'p' and 'o':

[image: Font rendering discrepancies in wkhtmltopdf]

We're running **wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)** on Ubuntu 14.04 server.  The font is installed locally onto the server in `/usr/share/fonts`.  I haven't noticed anything similar with other fonts.

Things we've tried so far:

- Playing with CSS properties `-webkit-font-smoothing` and `text-rendering` in our document
- Adding font config XML and using the `--zoom 1.3` flag mentioned here https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/45

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Sorry, no. Ended up switching to another font.

Answer (score 0):

Have similar problem when embed GothamPro  font with `@font-face` css property. 
And after spending a lot of time, resolve it with SVG fonts: change `src: url('GothamPro.ttf')` to `src: url('GothamPro.svg') format("svg");`

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem here  and no solution helped.

The FIX for me was to install wkhtmltopdf with "sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf" instead of using the precompiled binary or installing the .deb.